# Number list in IPython Notebook Markdown render with Roman numerals instead of numbers

Tags: markdown, jupyter-notebook

When I write

```
1. test 1
1. test 2
```

in a IPython Notebook markdown cell it renders as

```
 I. test 1
II. test 2
```

instead of

```
1. test 1
2. test 2
```

Why and how can I change it?

Thanks in advance

Mads

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the style of markdown cells. Also, when trying to define a list, IPython ignores the `<ol>` tag's `type` and `style` attributes. 
In order to get the numbers select one of the headings instead of "markdown" in cell style selection.

Comment: Ok, but I cannot make multiple line heading cells, and headings have a different format

Comment: Heading will carry structure in future version of notebook, please do not try to put heading in MD cell. As by markdown spec, the type of numbering of list is defined by css, so css is the way to change the numbering. Search for `IPython custom.css` (detail vary depending on IPython version.